# how to incorporate size polydispersity in colloidal suspensions

Tags: molecular-modeling, mathematical-modeling, monte-carlo, atomic-simulation-environment, fortran

Basically, I'm working on spherical colloids and investigating the phase behavior of these monodisperse colloids using Monte Carlo simulations (Fortran 77 coding). Now I want to introduce size polydispersity expressed in the gaussian distribution model into my code. Can anyone help?
I need the size polydispersity formula and how to write it using f77

Comment: Please don't use Fortran 77 - do yourself a favour and use something from the 21st century. Fortran 77 shouldn't have been used for new code in over 3 decades. As I said elsewhere Fortran 77 nowadays belongs in a museum.

Comment: Also it would help if you could make your question more focused - it's not my area but I suspect there are a number of different models of polydispersity, Is there one you are especially interested in?

Comment: size polydispersity expressing in gaussian distribution model

Comment: Please edit your question to include this information

Comment: to solve a specific problem we are  using F77, and we are almost solved the problem, to cross-check our results we need to calculate the size polydispersity.

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to help us solve it. Why can't your existing code incorporate size polydispersity? What have you tried, and what has happened when you've tried it?

Comment: @sivaram Please add relevant block of code where you are expecting the size polydispersity formula to be plugged in.  Without any code it is difficult for anyone to answer. Possibly a minimal reproducible code to show what you are expecting with sample input and output values.